# How to use strongly typed http methods in an Azure function signature

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I have a bunch of Azure functions that use an http trigger. I've been hard-coding http methods like in the below case:

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

Ideally, I'd like to use a strongly typed value instead of hard-coded strings like `get` and `post`. I tried using `HttpMethod` enum values, but I'm getting the below error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression , typeof
> expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Using C#, is there a way to leverage strongly typed http methods when declaring the function method signature?

Comment: What do you mean by “strongly typed” here?

Answer (score 4):

`nameof(HttpMethod.Get)` should work.